# AngularJS expression with Integers

Tags: angularjs, int, expression

I cant get this. How can I get first part of expression to pass? This only passes if item3 is set to 101. Id like it to pass when item1 is 101 and item2 is 100. This is used in segment of code where int parsing is required, because source can be either string or int.

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ddJ4Z/1/

```
<div data-ng-app="App" data-ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div data-ng-show="
      (parseInt(item1 == 101) && parseInt(item2 == 100)) || 
       parseInt(item3) == 101">Show me</div>
    <input data-ng-model="item1" />
    <input data-ng-model="item2" />
    <input data-ng-model="item3" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">"
    var app = angular.module('App',[]);
    app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.parseInt = parseInt;
        $scope.item1 = 100;
        $scope.item2 = 200;
        $scope.item3 = 300;
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol. It was a typo.

```
<div data-ng-show="
   ((parseInt(item1) == 101 && parseInt(item2) == 100) || 
     parseInt(item3) == 101)">Show me</div>
```

Here is working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ddJ4Z/4/